# Как задать размер окна в ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

Не могу найти соответствующей ф-ции в ncurses, чтобы задать размеры окна. Заодно подскажите как определить размеры уже открытого окна? Си, ncurses.

Comment: Воспользуйся [`wresize`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/wresize.3x.html) либо [`resizeterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html) (я так и не понял, в чём между ними разница). Размеры окна как будто бы хранятся в глобальных переменных [`LINES` и `COLS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_variables.3x.html).

Comment: @diraria, насколько я понял доку, `wresize` подгоняет внутренний размер ncurses-окна/данных под изменившийся размер экрана, а `resizeterm` в дополнение к этому может принудительно изменить размер экрана (например, окна эмулятора терминала)